# Permission error importing custom functions in Python Anaconda3 Mac OS Catalina

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, macos-catalina

**Set-up**

After updating to Catalina, Anaconda3 trouble commenced.

I've managed to solve most errors, doing a fresh install as [advised](https://www.anaconda.com/how-to-restore-anaconda-after-macos-catalina-update/) by Anaconda, but can't seem to get around a permission error when trying to importing functions from other .py files – something that worked just fine before I upgraded to Catalina.

I run Python 3.7 from Spyder 3.3.6.

---

**Error**

Whenever I try to import a custom function, I get,

```
import os
os.chdir('/Users/mypath/payment_management')
from payment_knab import pay_knab

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-cb99b6800e4e>", line 3, in <module>
    from payment_knab import pay_knab

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 963, in _find_and_load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 906, in _find_spec

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1280, in find_spec

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1249, in _get_spec

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1213, in _path_importer_cache

PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

---

**Question**

How do I run Anaconda/Spyder/Python with admin permission? Which command in terminal do I need to execute?

Stupidly enough I have actually managed to run with admin permission before via Terminal, but I forgot how...

I've been looking at StackOverflow for an hour now, but can't find anything that helps.

Answer (score -1):

You've probably forgotten again how to do this. Use `sudo spyder`, dummy.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) That's a terrible idea because you're running Spyder as root and a simple `os.remove('/')` will wipe your system! Instead please read [this](https://www.anaconda.com/how-to-restore-anaconda-after-macos-catalina-update/).